# Detect file type of a file using just the URL of file that is on a remote server using PHP when allow_url_fopen is disabled?

Tags: php, fopen, remote-server

I am building a PHP app which allows user to upload image files to the server by simply entering the URL of the image which is usually on a remote server.

StackOverflow also has this functionality when you upload image to the **Ask Question** screen.

My app will be part of a SugarCRM module which will be installed on many servers with different configurations and software.  For that reason I need to build my app to be as flexible as possible and try to account for as many setups as possible.

My biggest hurdle is servers that have the PHP INI setting `allow_url_fopen` set to false/off as it limits my choices for downloading remote files with a URL.

My question is more focussed on getting the file type of the remote file.  Many sites now days serve images without a file extension in there URL and also even if it does it can be spoofed I beleive.

Currently this is how the app gets the file extension of the file on the remote server...

```
$info = @GetImageSize($this->remote_image_url);
$mime = $info['mime'];

// What sort of image?
$fileType = substr(strrchr($mime, '/'), 1);
```

Looking at the PHP docs for `GetImageSize()` it says this...

> $filename This parameter specifies the file you wish to retrieve
>   information about. It can reference a local file or (configuration
>   permitting) a remote file using one of the supported streams.

**(configuration permitting) a remote file using one of the supported streams**

This is where the hurdle of **allow_url_fopen** being turned off on a server is my nightmare!

I can detect the status of `allow_url_fopen` with this...

```
if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')){
    return true;
}
```

So I could detect `allow_url_fopen` is on and if it is then I could use `GetImageSize()` to detect file type and when it is not enabled then make sure to not call that function.

---

**Question:**
So the question is how can I reliably get the file type of a remote file using just the URL to access the file on a server that has the PHP INI setting `allow_url_fopen` turned off?